# ¿Puedo crear dominios de internet ICANN en Ubuntu o Windows?

Tags: dns

¡Hola mundo! :D.

¿Puedo crear dominios de Internet en Ubuntu o Windows?, ¿o únicamente se pueden adquirir gratuitos o pagando a una registradora de dominios?.

Que pueda acceder cualquier usuario externo a través de la barra de búsquedas del navegador sin modificar el archivo hosts, sin pasos previos para el que va a visitar mi URL :)

Apache me creó un dominio al cual únicamente se puede acceder configurando el hosts en el segundo PC. Y según leí de Bind9 necesita la misma configuración. Con la IP sí he podido acceder desde cualquier IP externa tecleándola en la barra de búsquedas y me muestra la página de Apache perfecta  sin configurar nada en el cliente.

Ahora, quisiera lo mismo pero sin la IP, y sin pagar un dominio, y sin dominios gratuitos (No-ip...), y sin emparejar las dos maquinas. Solo quedaría crear mi propio dominio de internet en mi PC y que cualquier persona pueda acceder sin hacer más más que escribir la URL en el navegador.

Tengo Ubuntu 18.04 TLS. Si es posible, de cualquier forma a donde puedas indicarme iré por ahí a buscar. :)

Gracias por su atención. :)

Comment: Te falta mucho conocimiento sobre el funcionamiento del [sistema de nombres dominio](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_nombres_de_dominio) y del propio funcionamiento del NAT/PNAT de tu router de Internet (y de IP dinámicas). De manera muy escueta: no puedes crear dominios ICANN en tu máquina porque no perteneces a dicha organización ni gestionas los servidores raíz. Otra cosa diferente es que puedas crear dominios propios que funcionen en aquellas máquinas que usen tu servidor DNS como principal (en el momento que agreguen un secundario que no sea tuyo podrían dejar de funcionar).

Comment: Como te indican, los [registradores de dominio](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registrador_de_dominios) (domain name registrars) son los únicos que pueden crear dominios nuevos y se basan en una jerarquía DNS en la que no puedes participar si no adquieres, al menos, la gestión de un dominio y lo harás sólo bajo ese dominio. Es decir, una vez que adquieres un dominio, puedes crear tantos subdominios como desees si tú eres quien gestiona el servidor DNS de dicho dominio.